# Remove all elements\html but inputs

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a few input fields spread throughout the markup.

What I want to do is remove everything but the inputs from it.

So  this:

```
<form>
<table><tr><td>more info here<input type="submit" name="registerForEvent" id="registerForEvent" value="Register Online" class="Button" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>table goes here blah blah....
<table><tr><td></td><td>  test text here:<input type="hidden" name="test"></td></tr></table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

becomes this

```
<form>
<input type="submit" name="registerForEvent" id="registerForEvent" value="Register Online" class="Button" />
<input type="hidden" name="test">
</form>
```

I tried

```
$('form:not(input)').remove();
```

to no avail

http://jsfiddle.net/X5fFC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputs are children of children of the form, so removing the first children will remove the inputs as they themselves are children of those children etc?

Try moving all inputs to the form root level, then remove everything but the inputs:

```
$('input', 'form').appendTo('form');
$('*','form').not('input').remove(); ​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X5fFC/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You could store all inputs in a variable and then remove everything in the form. After that you can put back the inputs:

```
var inputs = $("form input");
$("form").empty().append(inputs);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5fFC/6/

Answer (score 2):

`$('form').html($('form input'));`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/X5fFC/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('form:not(input)').remove();
```

Will remove children `input` elements. You could try:

```
 var input = $('form input');
 $('form').empty().append(input);​
```